# Internet Connection from Switch but not directly from LAN Port

Tags: networking, internet, lan, switch

I noticed something strange at work today. At each office, we have a central LAN Port. This Port is responsible for the internet connection of 3 computers per office. So each of the computers is connected with a switch and the switch is then connected with the central Port. As I was experimenting a bit on my own I noticed something interesting. When I connected my computer with a LAN cable directly to the central Port, no internet connection could be established. However, when connected to the switch, the internet connection works fine.

I am not an expert on this field, so out of pure curiosity I wondered if somebody could explain to me how this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would consider static IP addressing and / or MAC or like filtering in the switches that may be responsible for this.

Comment: Is it more than a basic switch? Do you have IP phones on the network? It’s probable the switches are configured for vLANs and your computer does not talk the vLAN language. Essentially there are multiple logical networks being handed off to the switch through the central port. Each port on the switch is configured to pass one or more of those logical networks off to the connected device. This is not uncommon at all on business networks. Your computer can’t communicate on the central port because it is ignoring the vLAN encapsulation. But this is only a guess without direct insight to your LAN.